# Apache giving 400 error in Internet explorer

Tags: apache, http-status-code-400

I am hosting on Ubuntu 12.04 and getting a 400 error in Internet explorer.

However, I get no errors in Chrome or Firefox.

I have never seen this type of error before and am unsure how to go about debugging. What could be causing this?

Comment: could you ask some more detail please? Like the page you are trying to access, how, some code, etc

Comment: What are you hosting with apache? is it a .php script? static content? etc?. 400 errors means the client issued a bad request, this may happend if the script that handles the requests was expecting a parameter from the client (the browser) which it didn't get.

Comment: can you paste the URL? most likely a special character in the URL string not properly escaped

Comment: In you IE, press F12 (will open the Developer Console), and then take a look to your page request. There might be some(s) file(s) not properly loaded, leading IE to the 400. You can do this Network inspection your Chrome or Firebug as well.

Comment: Have you [googled](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&noj=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=bad+request+IE&oq=bad+requ&aq=0p&aqi=p-p1g9&aql=&gs_l=hp.3.0.35i39j0l9.4029.5387.0.6667.8.8.0.0.0.0.129.568.4j4.8.0...0.0.65CXGI7yhNI) the problem? There are many entries for this issue.